# How to invoke a method in windows 8 MetroStyleApp?

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I'm moving my windows application to windows8 metro style app, I don't know how to invoke a method in windows8 metrostyle app, My windows app Code is,

```
    private void appendLog(string msg)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { this.appendLog(msg); }));
    }
```

Can anyone say me!

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to accomplish but if it is something like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker.aspx) you should try

**Call code directly if called in UI thread, send it to UI thread otherwise:**

```
public void AppendLog(string msg)
{
    if (!Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess)
        Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, delegate { AppendLog(msg); });
    else
    {
        // DO YOUR UI STUFF
    }
}
```

If the method is called in UI thread the code is called directly, otherwise it is pushed to the dispatcher to be called in UI thread later...

Note: The method `AppendLog` has to be declared in a control. Only this way the `Dispatcher` property is available...

Comment: I Applied the Code u Gave and got this Warning : Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call. What do I do?

Comment: usually `*Async` methods are used with the `await` keyword. If you don't use await you can't use the result of the async method. In this case it's ok... ignore the warning... You should learn more about async/await here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx